# Error when opening terminal

Tags: 10.04, command-line, window

I have this error when opening any terminal windows:

```
bash: /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/32215/tasks: File o directory non esistente

bash: /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/32215/notify_on_release: File o directory non esistente

malik@malik-desktop:~$
```

What is this and how to solve? It doesn't seem to affect anything but it' annoying. Googling a bit lead me to sites talking about 200 lines kernel patch. I'm on 10.04 lts.

I went from 10.10 to 11.10 maintaining the /home and then rolled back to 10.04 with same /home.  / formatted.

Answer (score 1):

> Googling a bit lead me to sites talking about 200 lines kernel patch.

That was my immediate thought when I saw "cgroup". The patch was available as a bash-hack too so it might be possible that you've just applied that and it's not working now because the other setup (involving creating some boot-time scripts) isn't there on your new install.

You've got two options:

1. Remove the changes from `~/.bashrc`. They look like this:

   ```
   if [ "$PS1" ] ; then  
      mkdir -p -m 0700 /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$ > /dev/null 2>&1
      echo $$ > /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$/tasks
      echo "1" > /dev/cgroup/cpu/user/$$/notify_on_release
   fi
   ```
2. Repeat the whole setup process so it works again:

   - http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/alternative-to-200-lines-kernel-patch.html

Comment: removed those lines and didn't do anything else, solved thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would take the simple route

```
sudo rm ~/.bashrc
```

this method removes the offending file completely including your alias